# Atmospheric force on floor larger than weight

Tags: classical-mechanics, pressure, fluid-statics

In Fundamentals of Physics (Halliday, Resnick, Walker), Sample problem 15-1, the weight of the air in a room is calculated to be $420$ N, while the atmospheric force on the floor is calculated to be $1.5\times 10^6$ N. How can the force on the floor be so much larger than the weight of the air itself, and how do particles in the air exert a force on the floor?

Comment: Atmospheric force is due to the atmosphere and not just the room's air!

Answer (score 1):

> how do particles in the air exert a force on the floor?

If you fill your house with baseballs they also exert a force on the floor. Not all are in direct contact with the floor, but then they push down on some other ones which are.

Now, if you push on top of the top-most ball, then this push propagates all the way to the floor, which then has to carry all balls *plus* your push.

> the weight of the air in a room [...]  the atmospheric force on the floor  [...] How can the force on the floor be so much larger than the weight of the air itself

There are a certain amount of air molecules inside the room, just as there were balls before. Their total weight can be calculated regardless of any other pushes happening as well.

The floor must carry all these air molecules inside the room *as well as* any further push that might take place. If you have a window open, then the molecule at the edge but still inside is being pushed on by a molecule which is just outside the room. So here is an external force pushing into the room. Since the room is not airtight, this will always happen (was it airtight, then it *wouldn't* happen and the floor would *only* carry the weight of the air inside).

This propagates to the floow as well. In fact, you can usually consider the actual load on the floor as the weight of the air column vertically above it.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, the force is through atmospheric pressure, coming in from the windows and pushing against both the floor and the ceiling. Thus, if you draw a free-body force diagram for the air in the room, you see that it's exerting a force of $p_\mathrm{atm}A$ on the ceiling, $p_\mathrm{atm}A+mg$ on the floor, $p_\mathrm{atm}A_\mathrm w$ on the windows, and it's receiving the forces $mg$ from gravity, $p_\mathrm{atm}A_\mathrm w$ from the atmosphere outside through the windows, and the reciprocal pressure forces from the floor and the ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure is not just due to the weight of the air, it's due to the interactions of the matter in the air.

To illustrate this point, imagine the room is sealed, and the height can be changed while keeping the same amount of air inside.

If you raise the roof, the volume of the room would increase.  At the same time, there is still just as much air (and therefore mass/weight).  This air would be lower pressure, because the air molecules can move more freely and interact less (if you assume no heat transfer takes place).  This process is summarized by the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law).

You can rearrange the formula to show $$P = \frac {nRT}V$$
where $P$ is pressure, $n$ is amount of substance, $R$ is the [gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant), $T$ is temperature, and $V$ is volume.

The pressure is not only directly dependent on the mass (or amount of substance, $n$), but also on the amount of space it occupies, and the temperature.

As other answers have mentioned, pressure also works in every direction, while the mass only exerts a force downwards (due to gravity).

I believe this answer may address the first part of your question.  Steeven's answer explains the second part quite well in my opinion.